# #Angular2 How i can count numbers of custom attribute directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular-services, custom-directive

I made a custom `attr directive` and i will use it in siblings elements like:

```
<div>
   <div [customAttrDirective]="'value'">1</div>
   <div [customAttrDirective]="'value'">2</div>
   <div [customAttrDirective]="'value'">3</div>
   <div [customAttrDirective]="'value'">4</div>
</div>
```

I olso made a `service` that control all of my directives. Inside this it I want to know the count of my directives `customAttrDirective`.

PS: I can't do it by searching by class name(because i add classes inside the directive) and i can't do it by searching by attribute (directive name) because angular change.

Edit: replaced wrong sintax `customAttrDirective="'value'"` to `[customAttrDirective]="'value'"`

Many thanks.

Comment: I guess you are not using in the way you gave the example, otherwise you would put them in an ngFor which would make it esay to count, right?

Comment: You are right. I have a syntax error, edit it sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your custom attribute directive's class name is `CustomAttrDirective`, in the component that you are using your custom directives, add this:

`@ViewChildren(CustomAttrDirective) dirs: QueryList<CustomAttrDirective>`

Then in life circle `ngAfterViewInit`, get the length of variable `dirs`.

Comment: Did you get your count?

Comment: No and I need to  do it with service.

Comment: Inject your service into the component and save the count to your service, then you can access the count in other components.

Comment: I've used this an `this.dirs` is undefined in `ngAfterViewInit`, I was using component that was parent to my directives.